# What's the meaning of simple algebra?

Tags: representation-theory

I am reading a linear algebra material, in the book it mentioned :

> *Every simple algebra has an exact irreducible representation*

Could anyone provide a proof of this claim ?
And what is the more intuitive approach to understand the meaning of simple algebra?

Comment: An algebra is simple if the underlying ring has no other two-sided ideal than $(0)$ and itself.

Comment: I never heard about exact representations. Could you please tell us the definition of what an exact representation is?

Comment: @MathTheNovice just in case, Wikipedia has an entry about it with examples, here is the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_algebra